# Lazarus - TReplaceDialog - How to determine whether 'Replace' or 'Replace All' was clicked

Tags: replace, dialog, lazarus

I'm trying to add search and replace functionality to a `TSynEdit` component in a Lazarus project and I'm making use of `TSynEdit.SearchReplace()`, `TFindDialog` and `TReplaceDialog`.

All seems to be working as I need it, pretty much, except that I can't find a way of determining whether the 'Replace' or the 'Replace All' button was clicked on the replace dialog.

I have written the code for the `OnFind` event and for the `OnReplace` event but there doesn't seem to be an `OnReplaceAll` event.

Looking at the auto-help popup for the TReplaceDialog item I can't see any property or other that would allow me to determine which of the buttons had been pressed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

FM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `OnReplace` event, check to see if `frReplaceAll` is in the `Options`:

```
procedure TForm1.ReplaceDialog1Replace(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Sender as TReplaceDialog do
  begin
  if frReplace in Options then
    DoReplace(ReplaceDialog1.FindText, ReplaceDialog1.ReplaceText)
  else if frReplaceAll in Options then
    DoReplaceAll(ReplaceDialog1.FindText, ReplaceDialog1.ReplaceText);
  end;
end;
```

This example is from the [Delphi XE 4 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/TFindDialogOptions_%28Delphi%29), but the dialog should have the same basic implementation detail.

Comment: That got me on the right track! Thanks @Ken. I actually simplified it a little bit and am using `with Sender as TReplaceDialog do
      if frReplace in Options then
        Include(optionsForReplace,ssoReplace)
      else if frReplaceAll in Options then
       Include(optionsForReplace,ssoReplaceAll);` which is working perfectly.